# How to remove index value from merged dataframe in python using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I have two dataframes as below :

```
filename='C:\\HPTiB\\HPTib_Test_Cases\\template_276.xlsx'

test_excel_sh1=pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=0,index=False,index_col=None, header=0)
test_excel_sh1

SOURCE_KEY  PAYER NAME  PAYER CODE TYPE PAYER CODE
0     1      INDUSTRY   PAY             123485
1     2      LEADING    PAY             123422

test_excel_sh2=pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=1,index=False,index_col=None, header=0)
test_excel_sh2

 SOURCE_KEY RECIEVER_KEY    RECIEVER KEY TYPE   RECIEVER NAME   RECIEVER CODE

  0    1       1               PERSON               CEO             A222222221
  1    1       2               PERSON               CO-FOUNDER      A222222221
  2    2       3               PERSON               CFO             A222222221
```

while doing a merge on SOURCE_KEY as below :

```
df_left = pd.merge(test_excel_sh1, test_excel_sh2, on='SOURCE_KEY' , how='left')

SOURCE_KEY  PAYER NAME  PAYER CODE TYPE PAYER CODE  RECIEVER_KEY    RECIEVER KEY TYPE   RECIEVER NAME   RECIEVER CODE
0   1      INDUSTRY     PAY            123485       1               PERSON               CEO    A222222221
1   1      INDUSTRY     PAY            123485       2               PERSON              CO-FOUNDER  A222222221
2   2      LEADING      PAY            123422       3               PERSON               CFO    A222222221
```

Getting index values as well and when I am selecting two columns from above dataframes ( source_key and Reciever_key ) as below :

```
select_df=df_left[['SOURCE_KEY','RECIEVER_KEY']]

             SOURCE_KEY  RECIEVER_KEY
 0           1             1
 1           1             2
 2           2             3
```

Then while doing  a for loop on above :

```
for i ,j in select_df.iterrows():
    print("Value of SOurce key is " , i)
    print("Value of Reciever key is ", j)
```

OUTPUT :

```
Value of SOurce key is  0
Value of Reciever key is  SOURCE_KEY      1
RECIEVER_KEY    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
Value of SOurce key is  1
Value of Reciever key is  SOURCE_KEY      1
RECIEVER_KEY    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
Value of SOurce key is  2
Value of Reciever key is  SOURCE_KEY      2
RECIEVER_KEY    3
Name: 2, dtype: int64

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It is taking the value "i" as index  and renaming as source_key and receiever_key.
Is the any way I can remove these index values?

Comment: pd.DataFrame.iterrows() returns a tuple of row index and the row.   To access your SOURCE_KEY for each iteration use j['SOURCE_KEY']  instead of i inside your for loop.  Then for receiver key use j[''RECIVER_KEY'].

Comment: I didn't quit understand did you mean to Iterate over select_df.iterrows() like for j[SOURCE_KEY] , J[RECIEVER_KEY ] in in select_df.iterrows():  like this?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
for i ,j in select_df.iterrows():
    print("Value of Source key is " , j[0])
    print("Value of Reciever key is ", j[1])
```